# Possible test patterns produced by ATPG Software like Tetramax

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl

I am developing a pattern generator in VHDL for testing ICs. The problem is I need to make it as universal as possible and need to consider a few factors such as output rate, binary or tristate etc. I found out that the pattern files are generated by an ATPG software called Tetramax, but we don't have access to the software. It would be helpful if I could find out whether there is a norm for the test vectors.

We have one vector file in .wgl at hand, but to draw any conclusion I may need to learn how these ATPG software work. At least take a look at a few other pattern vector files that these software generate.

I appreciate any comments or help.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Your question is a little confusing...you want to develop a "pattern generator" then state that the pattern files are "generated" by ATPG software. Please clarify exactly how **your design** will function.

Comment: Thanks! It was named pattern generator, but actually it just forwards an already generated list of test vectors to the correct pin on the board. You can't do much processing on an FPGA so the test vectors have to be generated beforehand and saved in the RAM so that my pattern module could handle it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

ATPG generation is a very complex subject. We had a dedicated Design-For-Test<sup>*</sup> engineer full time handling the testing (and Tetramax). Wat I know about testing is mainly from glimpses over his shoulder.

What I saw was that ATPG patterns are often not externally made but internally using PRBS logic. You can bypass the PRBS and run your own vectors for detailed failure analysis.
Possible the patterns you have are used to control the test logic including the PRBS blocks.

Also in test mode the registers are converted into scan chains where the order is based on vicinity of other registers. Without knowledge about every logic gate in the design you are unlikely to understand what the test pattern files do.

Lastly:Generating the actual test pattern is the least problem. Most of the work is to find the best test coverage with the shortest pattern. You need to do a full circuit analysis with the test-vectors, for which you need to know about every gate in the design. To make a generic test pattern generator you are more likely going to need C or C++, access to the design library and a few hundred man years.

If there is a DFT engineer he may be able to answer your question about 'standards' for test vector formats.

<sup>*</sup><sub>*Never* call a Design-For-Test engineer a "test engineer". For some reason they find that very insulting.</sub>

Comment: I am not aware of the differences between test engineers and Design-For-Test Engineers. DFT engineers seem like an exotic kind.